In Norway, when number ranges are listed 3 times on a sign, what do they mean?
I saw in What does "No camping 10-21" mean?:

(Author: gerrit. License: CC BY-SA 4.0)
OP mentioned:

the times [10-21 on the sign] refer to weekdays, Saturdays, and Sundays/holidays, respectively

Is it just for this sign, or it is a convention/rule in Norway (and perhaps nearby countries too)?

Apparently it's a standard convention that is probably just common knowledge to anyone who lives in Norway. Presumably it's specified in some legal regulation but I haven't found it. Various unofficial sites list it, including wikipedia, and I found some for Sweden too. But I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting.

@NateEldredge Thanks. "I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting."  in that a convention/rule/etc. or just for this sign (eg maybe gerrit saw that the times [10-21 on the sign] refer to weekdays, Saturdays, and Sundays/holidays, respectively on the back of the sign? If a convention/rule, where? (maybe a why too if there's a reason) etc.

They read Wikipedia. This is a road sign, so somebody from Norway may confirm that it's covered in driver's license classes and tests. No parking signs are among the signs they can test you on in my US state.

I’m voting to close this question because 'How did they know' isn't travel related

While the “how did they know” part is indeed a bit OT, the question in the title (and the answer that would go with it, but is already in the question) is very relevant for travel.

@jcaron in that case, it's a duplicate question

@Berend I rephrased to make it clearer: "Is it just for this sign, or it is a convention/rule in Norway (and perhaps nearby countries too)?"

@Berend Duplicate with what question?

@Relaxed the one linked to in the question

Might clarify whether its a convention is in current usage rather than a convention that was used briefly but hardly applied to many signs.

@user2617804 Good point, that'd be great to have that info in the answers.

At this point the title "In Norway, when number ranges are listed 3 times on a sign, what do they mean?" is answered in the text of the question, and doesn't seem to match what the upvoted answer is answering...

@user3153372 it's not answered in the question, since gerrit's quote doesn't specify if it's for one given sign or any sign.

Interesting, the Italian symbols are quite different, and probably even more obscure to those who don't know it.

The short answer is "because it's convention". This form of signifying hours for different days of the week/holidays is used in many situations, whether parking place, store front, or on the bulletin board at the local community centre. These instances don't follow any official regulations, but trusts that the public understands the convention.
However, the Norwegian road authority (Vegvesenet) also uses this convention, and for them the regulations are written in the Norwegian laws, specifically chapter nine, subsection 18 of Skiltforskriften.

The text for 806 Tid says:

The supplementary sign specifies that the main sign only applies for
the period of time given by the hours. Black digits refer to weekdays
except Saturday, black digits in parenthesis refer to Saturday, red
digits refer to  Sunday, holidays and public days of celebration.

With this knowledge you might be able to infer when this supermarket is open, including that it's closed on Sundays and other "red" days.

meny.no
"Red days" is another convention you might run into, and the road signage regulation shows an example of it. In Norwegian a "red day" is any Sunday or other (Lutheran) holiday, or public day off, and they are indeed shown in red in our calendars:

www.norskkalender.no

+1. FWIW, the same convention applies in Finland and I'm pretty sure Sweden as well: https://www.ouka.fi/en/parking/parking-traffic-signs

It is the standard for road signs in Norway, Sweden, Finland and Denmark, but AFAIK not on Iceland and very commonly used in other places as well, e.g. as mentioned in this answer for opening hours. Since it is used like this in most North-European countries, it may be based on some other standard or specification predating road signs, but I have not been able to find anything about the history and background for such usage.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Given that it's really hard to drive to Iceland, I'm not surprised that they might have a different standard than Norway/Sweden/Finland/Denmark /s

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo: I don't think I've ever seen anything like this on store fronts in Denmark, I suspect because they are more liberal about opening hours. It might say eg. "8–21" and nothing else, meaning those are the opening hours every day. You might see two ranges given, but then the first one is for week-days and the second one for Saturday and Sunday.

@AkselA for clarity, do you know the supermarket in the picture is shut on Sundays because there isn't a third number/pair of numbers?

Thanks @njuffa but I'm trying to check how I infer it, as the answer says I can

@mattfreake: Yes. Though if it was open on Sundays it would most likely say "Søn. 10–18" or something similar, in red text.

Just got back from Iceland and did not see that.

@AkselA that's what I see on any shop that has Sunday hours - a set of red numbers separated from the rest, sometimes preceded by "Søn".

+1 for explaining "red days", I think the closest Anglophone analogue I found was "bank holidays".

Now I wonder what the difference is between holidays (helligdag) and public days of celebration (offentlig høytidstag).

@gerrit "holiday" in the strict sense applies only to religious days of celebration. In English the term is of course routinely used also for secular events, but "heilig" in Scandinavian (like German) is still a bit more specific, a "saintly day". Whereas a "høytid" (literally "high time") is simply any celebration.

In the UK, "bank holiday" is used for official days off such as Christmas but not only religious ones.  Despite the obvious derivation of the word, the origin is totally forgotten.  Over in the US, this term is not generally understood and "public holiday" is more usual.

@htmlcoderexe It seems like a close match but note my comment above.  "Bank holiday" is not typical in the US.  I don't recall the usage in other Anglophone countries.  I was in Canada once on one of these holidays.  I asked why it was a holiday.  The answer was: surely you know, it's Queen Victoria's birthday.  I didn't know that and it's not a holiday in the UK.
